# How to order documents in a collection in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem, after the version 9 update of Firebase, I cant seem to figure out how to order the documents in a collection.

Here is my code. I do not seem to understand how to implement the orderBy in the onSnapshot. Can someone please nudge me in the right direction. I have looked through the documentation but could not find a solution.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import SignOut from "./SignOut";
import { Grid, Typography, Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";
import db from "../firebase";
import { onSnapshot, collection, orderBy, query, limit } from "firebase/firestore";
import SendMessage from "./SendMessage";

function ChatBox() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(collection(db, "messages"), (snapshot) => {
      setMessages(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs="12" style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
          <SignOut></SignOut>
        </Grid>
        {messages.map(({ id, text, photoURL }) => (
          <Grid item xs="12" key={id} style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }}>
            <Avatar alt="" src={photoURL} />
            <Typography>{text}</Typography>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
      <Grid container>
        <SendMessage></SendMessage>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}

export default ChatBox;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution:

When you use the order by, if the field you are trying to order the documents by does not excist in the document, the order by will not "store" and order that document. Next, in my chat application I created a field with the `Timestamp` constructor that Firebase offers. That allowed me to order the documents in the `createdAt` order.

My code for the ChatBox file:
Chatbox.js

```js
import { collection, query, onSnapshot, orderBy } from "firebase/firestore";
//OTHER CODE
useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(query(collection(db, "messages"), orderBy("createdAt")), (snapshot) => {
      setMessages(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    });
  }, []);
```

SendMessage.js

```js
import { collection, addDoc, Timestamp } from "firebase/firestore";
//OTHER CODE
const [userMessage, setUserMessage] = useState("");
  async function sendUserMessage(e) {
    const auth = getAuth();
    e.preventDefault();
    const { uid, photoURL } = auth.currentUser;
    await addDoc(collection(db, "messages"), {
      text: userMessage,
      photoURL,
      uid,
      createdAt: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
    });
  }
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

In JS API v9 we have to perform everything in a functional way.
To order the collection before you attach a listener, you need to perform a query. A query can take a reference, order the results and pass the results to the caller.

In other words, your code should look like this:

```
import { onSnapshot, collection, orderBy, query, limit } from "firebase/firestore";
//OTHER CODE
useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(query(collection(db, "messages"), orderBy("YOUR_FIELD")), (snapshot) => {
      setMessages(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    });
  }, []);
```

Change YOUR_FIELD with the reference to any field you want to use to order the results.
What we are doing here is:

- getting a reference to a collection
- asking firestore to perform a query on that collection, ordering the results by a field
- attaching a listener to the results

Comment: Hi, I have tried doing it this way but I get nothing displayed on my page when I run this. I dont get errors, but it seems as if the array is empty if I do it this way? Any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Hi can you can try this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(query(collection(db, "messages").orderBy('createdAt').startAfter(today)), 
      (snapshot) => {
      setMessages(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
    }); 
    }, []);
```

Comment: That's the v8 syntax. In v9, CollectionReference no longer has the orderBy method and a lot of other methods, because the API has been changed to become a functional API

Comment: I understand you , so try to add a query on that collection to get the response

Comment: Jup, this does not work with v9